# Converting maven to gradle of Spring Initializr

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-initializr

Spring Initializr is a open source project , which can be downloaded/cloned from github to run our own spring initializr. however the build of the project is maven. I want to convert it to gradle. Can anyone Help ?

I tried it with gradle init and gradle build
Gradle init is creating build.gradle and settings.gradle but gradle build is giving error.

Can someone try and post the solution

Thanks in advance

Error Details :

```
Task :initializr-actuator:compileTestJava FAILED
D:\Duplicate1\initializr\initializr-actuator\src\test\java\io\spring\initializr\actuate\ActuatorIntegrationTests.java:19: error: package io.spring.initializr.web does not exist
import io.spring.initializr.web.AbstractFullStackInitializrIntegrationTests;
                           ^
D:\Duplicate1\initializr\initializr-actuator\src\test\java\io\spring\initializr\actuate\ActuatorIntegrationTests.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
            extends AbstractFullStackInitializrIntegrationTests {
                    ^
symbol: class AbstractFullStackInitializrIntegrationTests
D:\Duplicate1\initializr\initializr-actuator\src\test\java\io\spring\initializr\actuate\info\BomRangesInfoContributorTests.java:24: error: package io.spring.initializr.test.metadata does not exist
import io.spring.initializr.test.metadata.InitializrMetadataTestBuilder;
                                     ^
D:\Duplicate1\initializr\initializr-actuator\src\test\java\io\spring\initializr\actuate\metric\ProjectGenerationMetricsListenerTests.java:28: error: package io.spring.initializr.test.metadata does not exist
import io.spring.initializr.test.metadata.InitializrMetadataTestBuilder;
                                     ^
D:\Duplicate1\initializr\initializr-actuator\src\test\java\io\spring\initializr\actuate\stat\AbstractInitializrStatTests.java:23: error: package io.spring.initializr.test.metadata does not exist
import io.spring.initializr.test.metadata.InitializrMetadataTestBuilder;
                                     ^
D:\Duplicate1\initializr\initializr-actuator\src\test\java\io\spring\initializr\actuate\stat\MainControllerStatsIntegrationTests.java:24: error: package io.spring.initializr.web does not exist
import io.spring.initializr.web.AbstractFullStackInitializrIntegrationTests;
                           ^
D:\Duplicate1\initializr\initializr-actuator\src\test\java\io\spring\initializr\actuate\stat\MainControllerStatsIntegrationTests.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
            extends AbstractFullStackInitializrIntegrationTests {
                    ^
symbol: class AbstractFullStackInitializrIntegrationTests
7 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':initializr-actuator:compileTestJava'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.8.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 4s
11 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 10 up-to-date

Comment: Can you mention error deatils?

Comment: added error details @VivekPakmode

Comment: `gradle init` is a first step in converting from maven to gradle and often needs some manual tweaking. It seems that the `dependencies { ... }` block is missing the jar/project which defines `io.spring.initializr.web`. Please compare the `pom.xml` and `build.gradle` for the failing project and look for differences in the dependencies. If you want further help I suggest you include the dependencies sections from both

Comment: @lance-java , I have compared both pom.xml and build.gradle, all dependencies are present .

Comment: @lance-java FYI : You can clone the spring initializr in your local and try. you will know the exact issue.

Comment: I'm not going to do your job for you. If you want further help, include the dependencies section from pom.xml and generated build.gradle from the failing project. It's probably also best to mention where `io.spring.initializr.web.*` java sources are located

Comment: @lance-java , I have added the dependencies section from pom to  build.gradle as you suggested . Now build.gradle is unable to compile.

Comment: Huh? No idea what you're doing. Paste the relevant dependency sections from pom.xml and build.gradle here, in your stack overflow question, so we can help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting that you can generate fresh project from following url:

https://start.spring.io/

Select Gradle Project and download the code.

Comment: Thanks , but I know that. here What I am doing is customizing spring initializr itself.

Comment: It looks like some dependencies are missing try to add the right artifacts